# Meaning of a sentence with "être preneur"

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

J'ai lu dans un email :

> Le labo est à la recherche de son scanner 3D sense.
>
> **Si vous avez une information dessus, nous sommes preneur**.

1) Je ne comprends pas l'emploi de *dessus* ici.

2) Que signifie *nous sommes preneur* dans ce contexte ?

3) Pourquoi pas nous sommes preneur**s** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I** Dans cette phrase « dessus » signifie « à propos de cela », concernant cela » ou encore « qui ce rapporte à cela » et dit encore différemment « à ce sujet ». On pourrait aussi dire « là-dessus » ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=information+l%C3%A0-dessus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinformation%20l%C3%A0%20-%20dessus%3B%2Cc0)).

**II** Cela signifie « vouloir connaitre l'information disponible » dans le cas présent, et généralement « être intéressé ». ([réf.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_preneur)).

**I** Très apparemment, il ne peut s'agir que d'une erreur. Il n'est pas clair dans cette locution s'il s'agit du nom « preneur » ou de l'adjectif, mais il semble que quelle que soit la nature de ce mot il faudrait un s à la fin de preneur ; c'est en tous cas la seule façon de l'écrire dans les livres ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sommes+preneurs%2Csommes+preneur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csommes%20preneurs%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csommes%20preneurs%3B%2Cc0)) ; pour l'expression « être acheteur », de même un s est utilisé (nous sommes acheteurs) et « acheteur » est un nom aussi bien qu'un adjectif ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nous+sommes+acheteurs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnous%20sommes%20acheteurs%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnous%20sommes%20acheteurs%3B%2Cc0)).

**IV** En réponse à un commentaire de user **Dimitris** (*Avez-vous des sources sur la provenance de cette expression ? Est-elle courante ? Je crois ne pas l'avoir entendu une seule fois auparavant.*)

Je n'ai pas de preuve écrite de la source du sens premier ou une étymologie pour ainsi dire. Ce que l'on peut dire c'est que le présent sens est le résultat d'un glissement récent que l'on peut vérifier dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/preneur) parce que l'on ne trouve pas l'acception qui a été mentionnée ci-dessus (« être intéressé »). J'ai souvent entendu cette expression au cours de ma vie et elle n'a jamais eu ce sens ; le sens courant qu'elle a toujours eu est le sens « C » du TLFi.

> C. − Personne disposée à acheter ou à conclure un marché. Synon. acheteur, acquéreur.
>
> - Être preneur du lot; trouver preneur à bon prix. Courtin: (...) Je vous offre ma fille (...) Je donne cinq cent mille francs (...) Oui ou non. Chavarot: Permettez (...) une proposition aussi inattendue (...) Courtin: Réponse!... J'ai preneur! Chavarot: Je prends! (Labiche, Ptes mains, 1859, i, 13, p.38).

On l'utilisait dans le cadre de transactions moyennant une rétribution financière, essentiellement, et il doit rester une solide proportion de la population qui préserve ce sens. Néanmoins ce mot semble avoir été détourné de son sens premier. Il faut dire que dans la littérature récente la nouvelle acception est bien plus souvent celle dont il est question alors que l'acception initiale se fait rare, cette information étant issue d'un rapide examen des livres récents. Voilà un ngram qui montre que c'est une locution de plus en plus utilisée et donc, d'après les livres, de plus en plus utilisé selon son nouveau sens : [réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+preneur%2Csuis+preneur%2Csommes+preneurs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cest%20preneur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuis%20preneur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csommes%20preneurs%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Merci. Avez-vous des sources d'où vient cette expression ? Est-elle courante ? Je crois ne pas avoir l'entendu une autre fois.

Comment: @Dimitris Vous trouverez une réplique à ce dernier commentaire dans une addition à ma réponse.

Answer (score 3):

1) "Dessus" ici doit être vu comme un raccourci de "sur ce scanner".

2) Dans ce contexte, "nous sommes preneurs" signifie "nous acceptons volontiers [toute information]."

3) C'est une faute d'orthographe, en théorie "preneur" s'accorde, comme tu l'as deviné.

Comment: Merci. 1) Est-ce que tu sais d'où vient cet emploi de dessus ? et 2) Quelle est l'origine de cette expression (être preneur.e.s) ?

Comment: Bienvenue à FSE by the way:-)!

Comment: Merci ;) 1) Je ne sais pas vraiment, ça pourrait être une extension de l'utilisation de "sur" comme synonyme de "à propos de" : "j'aimerais avoir plus d'informations sur le scanner"... 2) il n'y a pas à chercher loin ! Un preneur est une personne qui prend quelque chose, tout simplement ; par extension, c'est une personne qui est d'accord pour acquérir quelque chose. C'est donc autant une expression qu'un mot tout bête.

Comment: 2) j'ajouterai que la vente d'informations a toujours un moyen de faire un marché (même si ce n'est pas vraiment une vente ici), donc *tu peux prendre des informations en échange d'argent / d'un objet*

Answer (score 1):

Je vais seulement réagir sur le *preneur*.

Pour moi il ne s'agit pas forcément d'une faute mais peut-être du **nous de modestie / de majesté**, qui consiste à remplacer *je* par *nous* dans un soucis de modestie, de politesse ou pour représenter une autorité.

Cela me paraît plausible dans un contexte où l'on s'exprime à la place d'un labo, pour demander quelque chose. Dans ce cas l'accord se fait au singulier et selon le genre de la personne qui parle. Exemple de cette utilisation :

> Nous avons été contrainte de publier une version abrégée de cette étude.

Le pluriel serait évidemment correct et représenterait l'ensemble des individus du labo.